# How do I allow Alfred.app to control Bluetooth on macOS Sonoma?

Tags: terminal, alfred, sonoma, macos

So I have Run Script actions in my Alfred workflows that uses the command `blueutil -p 0` to turn bluetooth off.

After upgrading to macOS Sonoma 14.0, the command stops working when invoked by Alfred workflow (see the error output at the bottom), but it runs fine from terminal (after I granted terminal the access to control this in the prompt).

I think I need to grant Alfred access to do that to, but the prompt never shows for Alfred, and I cannot find where to do that in Settings.

So how do I allow Alfred.app to control Bluetooth on macOS Sonoma?

Alfred workflow log:

```
/Users/tscp/Library/Caches/com.runningwithcrayons.Alfred/Workflow Scripts/7B5E7523-370A-4986-82B1-539195A20C3C: line 3: 43540 Abort trap: 6           /usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 0
```

The file at `/Users/tscp/Library/Caches/com.runningwithcrayons.Alfred/Workflow Scripts/7B5E7523-370A-4986-82B1-539195A20C3C` contains the content of the my Run Script action, and the `/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 0` is on line 3 of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow Bluetooth for **Alfred 5** in macOS Settings **Privacy & Security > Bluetooth > Alfred 5**

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: I have no idea how you figured this out but thank you. I was skeptical a Google search for 'alfred "Abort trap"' would take me anywhere useful but here I am.